# XMPP web client simulate multiple account

Tags: xmpp, strophe

How to simulate multiple account in jsjac or strophe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strophe support multiple account at the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Strophe or jsjac, but with XMPP in general each account requires a seperate XMPP connection.